# Please Help me with this 404 error

Tags: 404-error, fonts

[image: Help regarding 404 error and how to fix this I don't know anything about this please help where to redirect]

Please Help i dont know how to fix this issue nor im eligible to understand the technichal terms. Just wanna know where to redirect these

Comment: You'll need to speak with your website maintainer or your hosting provider.

Comment: Are these URLs on your own site? Because fonts.gstatic.com is obviously meant to be another site. Can you show us where you have these URLs in the CSS? Are you missing `https://` at the start of all of these URLs, so they think they're relative URLs when they're not supposed to be?